# Showing Position Operator is Unbounded

Tags: functional-analysis

For example 1, on the Unbounded Operators section in Reed's "Functional Analysis", they mention that the position operator $T: D(T) \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$, with $(T\varphi)(x) = x \varphi(x)$ is unbounded. The domain is defined as

$$D(T) = \left\{\varphi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) : \int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2|\varphi(x)|^2dx < \infty\right\}.$$

To show it is unbounded in general, can we just quickly apply the definition of boundedness here?

For any $\varphi \in D(T)$,

$$
\begin{align}
||T|| &= \sup_{||\varphi||_2 = 1} ||T\varphi||_2 \\
&= \sup_{||\varphi||_2 = 1} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2|\varphi(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2} \\
&= \sup_{||\varphi||_2 = 1} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\varphi(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2} \tag{$\varphi$ constant in $L^2$-norm}\\
&= \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2dx\right)^{1/2} \\
&= \infty.
\end{align}
$$

---

EDIT: For completeness, using the accepted we have

$$||T|| = \sup_{||\varphi||_2 = 1} ||T\varphi||_2 \geq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ||T\chi_{(n, n+1)}||_2 = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sqrt{\frac{2n + 1}{2}} = \infty.$$

Comment: The equality of the arguments in the second and third line does no hold for any $\phi\in L^2$ with $\|\phi\|_2=1$. So how do you prove that the suprema coincide?

Comment: Ah, yes. I guess this should actually be $\geq$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\|\chi_{(n,n+1)} \|^{2}=1$ for each $n$ and $\|T\chi_{(n,n+1)} \|^{2}\to \infty$. Hence, $T$ is unbounded.